# Automatic reuse same-property materials

Tags: python, scripting, materials

I have many objects created by importing some `.wrl` files and joining several meshes toghether. The result is a set of blender objects, each with a long list of materials from its submeshes. However, these - nearly a thousand - materials are only ten different colors or so...

I know that I can manually create ten "master materials" and assign each mesh to the proper color (following the manual: [reusing-existing-materials](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/assigning_a_material.html#reusing-existing-materials)), but it is really annoying...

Is there a way to automatically "skim" the materials to ends up with a small list of colors reused by all the submeshes of the objects?

I mean something like this:

```
list_of_unique_materials = []
for material in bpy.data.materials:
    if material.users:
        if not **material in list_of_unique_materials**:
            list_of_unique_materials.append(material)
        else:
            **reuse the same material in the list**
```

where I'm not really sure about how to implement the code inside the asterisks...

Many thanks!

### EDIT: Example

What I have now (`len(bpy.data.materials) >> 805`):

- Object1

  - Mesh.001: Material.001
  - Mesh.002: Material.002
  - Mesh.003: Material.003 **(same as Material.001)**
  - Mesh.004: Material.004
  - ...
- Object2

  - Mesh.101: Material.101 **(same as Material.001)**
  - Mesh.102: Material.102 **(same as Material.002)**
  - Mesh.103: Material.103 **(same as Material.002)**
  - Mesh.104: Material.104 **(same as Material.004)**
  - ...
- ...

What I would like (`len(bpy.data.materials) >> 12`):

- Object1

  - Mesh.001: Material.001
  - Mesh.002: Material.002
  - Mesh.003: **Material.001**
  - Mesh.004: Material.004
  - ...
- Object2

  - Mesh.101: **Material.001**
  - Mesh.102: **Material.002**
  - Mesh.103: **Material.002**
  - Mesh.104: **Material.004**
  - ...
- ...

This is due to the `.wrl` importer which has named with a new identifier every single color of the meshes that I have imported (and the total number of distinct colors in the meshes is no more than 12).

Comment: Is this part of an importer? What exactly are you meaning to do when you say "reuse", just not adding it to the list?

Comment: I mean something like what has explained in the manual linked above. I've also added an example to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made up this workaround:

```
import bpy

def find_material(material, list):
    for elem in list:
        if material.diffuse_color == elem.diffuse_color and \
           material.specular_color == elem.specular_color:
            return elem
    return False

# creates a list of unique materials
list_of_unique_materials = []
for material in bpy.data.materials:
    if material.users and not find_material(material, list_of_unique_materials):
        list_of_unique_materials.append(material)

# updates materials of each mesh
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    for mat in obj.material_slots:
        mat.material = find_material(mat.material, list_of_unique_materials)

# removes unused materials
for material in bpy.data.materials:
    if not material.users:
        bpy.data.materials.remove(material)
```